# How can I remove a section number from the heading but not figure captions?

Tags: sectioning

I'm preparing a thesis with only one appendix section and the university submission guidelines have some funny requirements. Particularly because there's only one appendix, the chapter heading should read simply "Appendix" (instead of "Appendix A"), but if I suppress the numbering with `\chapter*{}`, all of the figures in that section lose their section identifier as well (Figure 1, Figure 2, etc.). It'd be nice to preserve the A1, A2... numbering for consistency; how can I keep the figures labeled by their section while suppressing the section number in the heading?

Comment: Add `\markboth{Appendix}{}` right after `\chapter{Appendix title}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can issue `\stepcounter{chapter}` before `\chapter*{Appendix}`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} % Just to prduce smaller document for illustration

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \rule{4cm}{2cm}
  \caption{First figure}
\end{figure}

\appendix
\stepcounter{chapter}
\chapter*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix} % To add Appendix to the TOC

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \rule{4cm}{2cm}
  \caption{Appendix figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Page 1]
>   [image: Page 2]